# VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp reference in VB.Net

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

This is a basic question that I haven't been able to find an answer to:

How do I set a reference to VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp in VB.Net 2010?

I understand that VB.Net has a better regex engine built in, but I want to refer to the version that's available in VBA. I'm thinking about creating a small VB.Net tool for Excel VBA programmers.

I'm able to set a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime as I would in VBA, but there's no Regex member that I've been able to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to the following library:

```
Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
```

That will give you the VBScript regex class:

```
Dim re
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = ""
...
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that in the list before.